# Putting inputs under labels

Tags: html, css

I've been trying for days but I couldn't make this work, how do I achieve this? I can't figure it out, how do I put two labels (fname lname) on the same line and under them the corresponding inputs?[here's a sketch of what i wanna do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSX9L.png)

I know it's an easy task for you all but I'm stuck on it, I can do it but they end up on separate lines or I only get the first one done but the label on the second one disappears

Comment: You can do this using `flex` or `grid`, read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Answer (score 1):

Here you go, no need for flex/grid:

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<label>
  First Name
  <input/>
</label>
<label>
  Last Name
  <input/>
</label>
```

Comment: No worries, feel free to upvote helpful answers and/or accept as an answer if it answered your question, cheers!

Comment: Great answer, may I ask is it not bad for html structure (semantic html aspect) to put input inside the label?

Comment: @AliNavidi No it isn't since the accessible name computation will result in the same as it being outside and leveraging the `for` attribute. So ultimately this comes down to stylistic preference since the browser automagically does this for you.

Comment: Yeah, semantically both are fine. In my experience rarely we can keep input inside of the label unfortunately due to styling requirements. I don't like "label for" approach because you might run into ID collisions. But doesn't really matter :)

Answer (score 1):

As the commenter noted, CSS Grid is going to be your preferred approach for this type of setup. Here is a working [example](https://jsbin.com/jacefivigu/edit?html,css,output).

Here is your HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div><label for="fname">First Name</label></div>
    <div><label for="lname">Last Name</label></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="fname"></div>
    <div><input type="text" name="lname"></div>
</div>
```

Then the CSS to setup your grid:

```
.container {
  display: grid; 
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr; 
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; 
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

So what is this doing? There are different types of `display` values within CSS. Many HTML elements have default values, such as a `div` has a display of `block` whereas our `input` elements have an `inline-block`. This tells the browser how to do layout of that element.

So in our case, we're first going to set it to leverage a relatively new layout paradigm called `grid`. CSS Grid is powerful because it allows you to define layouts in two dimensions. CSS Grid items are its direct descendants which is why I added seemingly pointless `div`s as container elements for each item.

So let's dig into what each line is doing.

`display: grid` - This tells the browser to use Grid when laying out that element

`grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;` - This is defining how many columns we want our grid to have and how to size them. We're going to use the [flexible length unit](https://css-tricks.com/introduction-fr-css-unit/) (fr) in order to size both columns.

`grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;` - Like rows, this is defining how many columns we want our grid to have and how to size them.

`grid-auto-rows: 1fr;` - Grid is powerful, and even though we've defined that we'll have a 2x2 grid there are scenarios where new content may be inserted that the CSS author wasn't aware of. If there isn't a cell that the un-accounted for item can be placed into then CSS Grid will create a new row to insert the content into, these are known as implicit rows and columns. Here we're defining how large we want those rows to be if there ends up being more than two rows of content.

CSS Grid is very powerful and I highly recommend Rachel Andrew's "[Grid by Example](https://gridbyexample.com/examples/)" and just clicking from the first one until the end and you'll have a rather strong grasp on how to use CSS Grid.

Have fun!